# What does -B and -f flag do in Maven command?

Tags: maven-3

For example:

```
mvn -B -f pom.xml....
```

What do they do? I found it somewhere in a code. I tried to google it out but didn't find any useful information. I'm new in Maven, only have basic understanding.

What I found in a code running on Jenkins CI/CD pipeline:

```
bat '''cmd.exe /C "'''+mavenVersion+''' -B -f pom.xml install....'''
```

Comment: what about -f flag ? Thank you !

Comment: `mvn --help` will show you

Comment: got it ! Thanks man ! @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 33):

I got my answer using `mvn --help` command. Thanks stackoverflow community !

`-B` : Run in non-interactive (batch) mode (disables output color)

`-f` : Force the use of an alternate POM file (or directory with pom.xml)